# Html5 canvas elasticity animation

Tags: html, html5-canvas

i want to add elasticity to the existing animation by making the circle and line return to its original position when dragged.

I have tried using mouseclick and mousedown, but not working. Here's the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/vinito/byw7to95/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    #canvasOne
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <canvas id="canvasOne" width="950" height="700">
        </canvas>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
    var myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

    init();

    var numShapes;
    var shapes;
    var dragIndex;
    var dragging;
    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    var dragHoldX;
    var dragHoldY;
    var timer;
    var targetX;
    var targetY;
    var easeAmount;
    var bgColor;

    function init()
    {
        numShapes = 5;              
        shapes = [];

        makeShapes();
        drawScreen();   
        myCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener, false);   
    }

    function makeShapes()
    {
        var tempX;
        var tempY;
        var tempRad;        
        var tempGrad;
        var gradFactor = 2;

        for(var i = 0; i < numShapes; i++)
        {           
            //random position
            tempRad = 40;
            var centerX = myCanvas.width/2;
            var centerY = myCanvas.height/2;

            if(i == 0)
            {
                tempX = centerX
                tempY = centerY;
            }
            else
            {
                //tempX = Math.random() * (myCanvas.width - tempRad);
                //tempY = Math.random() * (myCanvas.height - tempRad);
                //150 can be actual radius in degrees
                tempX = centerX + 250 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / numShapes);
                tempY = centerY + 250 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / numShapes);
            }

            tempColor = "#4285F4";
            tempShape = {x: tempX, y: tempY, rad: tempRad, color: tempColor};

            shapes.push(tempShape);         
        }       
    }

    function mouseDownListener(evt)
    {
        var highestIndex = -1;

        var bRect = myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouseX = (evt.clientX - bRect.left) * (myCanvas.width/bRect.width);
        mouseY = (evt.clientY - bRect.top) * (myCanvas.height/bRect.height);

        for(var i = 0; i < numShapes; i++)
        {
            if(hitTest(shapes[i], mouseX, mouseY))
            {
                dragging = true;
                if(i > highestIndex)
                {
                    dragHoldX = mouseX - shapes[i].x;
                    dragHoldY = mouseY - shapes[i].y;
                    highestIndex = i;
                    dragIndex = i;
                }               
            }
        }

        if(dragging)
        {
            window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveListener, false);
        }

        myCanvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener, false);
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpListener, false);

        if(evt.preventDefault)
        {
            evt.preventDefault;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function mouseUpListener(evt)
    {
        myCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener, false);
        window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpListener, false);

        if(dragging)
        {
            dragging = false;
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveListener, false);
        }
    }

    function mouseMoveListener(evt)
    {
        var shapeRad = shapes[dragIndex].rad;

        var minX = shapeRad;
        var maxX = myCanvas.width - shapeRad;

        var minY = shapeRad;
        var maxY = myCanvas.height - shapeRad;

        //get mouse position correctly
        var bRect = myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouseX = (evt.clientX - bRect.left)*(myCanvas.width / bRect.width);
        mouseY = (evt.clientY - bRect.top)*(myCanvas.height / bRect.height);

        //clamp x and y position to prevent object from dragging outside canvas
        posX = mouseX - dragHoldX;
        posX = (posX < minX) ? minX : ((posX > maxX) ? maxX : posX);
        posY = mouseY - dragHoldY;      
        posY = (posY < minY) ? minY : ((posY > maxY) ? maxY : posY);

        shapes[dragIndex].x = posX;
        shapes[dragIndex].y = posY;

        drawScreen();       
    }

    function hitTest(shape, mx, my)
    {
        var dx = mx - shape.x;
        var dy = my - shape.y;

        return(dx * dx + dy * dy < shape.rad * shape.rad);
    }

    //drawing both shape (line and circle) and screen

    function drawScreen()
    {
        myContext.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        myContext.fillRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
        drawShapes();
    }

    function drawShapes()
    {

        //line
        for(var i = 1; i < numShapes; i++)
        {
            myContext.beginPath();
            myContext.moveTo(shapes[0].x, shapes[0].y);
            myContext.lineTo(shapes[i].x, shapes[i].y);
            myContext.stroke();
        }

        //circle        
        for(var i = 0; i < numShapes; i++)
        {
            myContext.fillStyle = shapes[i].color;
            myContext.beginPath();
            myContext.arc(shapes[i].x, shapes[i].y, shapes[i].rad, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
            myContext.closePath();
            myContext.fill();
        }       
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The events and callbacks are correctly fired, what you need is thinking the logic of what you want to do : On a mouse click and drag, you want your shape to follow the mouse. On a mouse Up, you want to restore the shape to its previous location ? If so, you need to store the shape's previous position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Here's one way to move a circle away from its origin and animate it back

---

**Move a circle (drag or programmatically) away from its original position**

Listen for mouse events:

- On mousedown, test if the mouse was downed inside the circle. If yes, save the mouse position and set a flag indicating a drag operation has begun.
- On mousemove, calculate the distance the mouse has moved since the last mousemove event and move the circle by that distance.
- On mouseup (or mouseout), clear the isDragging flag, start an animation loop to animate the circle back to its original position, and set a flag indicating an animation has begun.

**To animate a circle back to its original position**

Create an animation loop using `requestAnimationFrame`.

- Calculate how long the animation has been running (==elapsed time).
- The circle will be animated from its dragDrop position back to its original position. Calculate the current circle position based on elapsed time. You can use one of [Robert Penner's](http://robertpenner.com/easing/) Easing functions to add easing effects to the animation.
- Clear the canvas and redraw the circle in its currently rebounding position
- If the animation is complete (==circle is back to its origin) then clear the isAnimating flag. Otherwise, request another animation frame if the animation is not yet complete.

**Here's a annotated example code and a Demo:**

```js
// canvas vars
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

// drag vars
var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

// animation vars
var originalX=50;
var originalY=50;
var radius=30;
var stretchedX=originalX;
var stretchedY=originalY;
var duration=1000;
var startTime=0;
var isAnimating=false;

// set canvas styles
ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray';
ctx.lineWidth=3;

// listen for mouse events
$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});

draw(originalX,originalY);

function animate(time){
    // not animating, just return
    if(!isAnimating){return;}
    
    // calc how long the animation has been running
    var elapsed=time-startTime;
    if(elapsed>duration){ elapsed=duration; }
    
    // calc the current x,y using easing
    var x=easeOutBounce(elapsed,stretchedX,originalX-stretchedX,duration);
    var y=easeOutBounce(elapsed,stretchedY,originalY-stretchedY,duration);

    // draw the scene
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    draw(x,y);

    // if the animation isn't done, request a new frame
    if(isAnimating && elapsed>=duration){
        // done, turn off animation
        isAnimating=false;            
    }else{
        // more animating to be done
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

}

function draw(x,y){
    // draw small circle in original position
    // draw larger circle in dragged position
    // connect 2 circles with line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(originalX,originalY);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
    ctx.moveTo(originalX,originalY);
    ctx.arc(originalX,originalY,5,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // if the mouse is down in the circle
  // start dragging
  var dx=startX-originalX;
  var dy=startY-originalY;
  if(dx*dx+dy*dy<radius*radius){
      isAnimating=false;
      isDown=true; 
  }
}

function handleMouseUpOut(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}         

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // stop dragging, start animating
  isDown=false;
  stretchedX=mouseX;
  stretchedY=mouseY;
  isAnimating=true;
  startTime=performance.now();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // calc distance mouse has moved since last mousemove event
  var dx=mouseX-startX;
  var dy=mouseY-startY;
  startX=mouseX;
  startY=mouseY;

  // draw the scene
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  draw(mouseX,mouseY);
  
}

// easing functions 
// Thank you Robert Penner: http://robertpenner.com/easing/
function easeInBounce(t, b, c, d){
  return c - easeOutBounce(d-t, 0, c, d) + b;
}
function easeOutBounce(t, b, c, d){
  if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
    return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
  } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
    return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
  } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
    return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
  } else {
    return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
  }
}
function easeInOutBounce(t, b, c, d){
  if (t < d/2) return easeInBounce(t*2, 0, c, d) * .5 + b;
  return easeOutBounce(t*2-d, 0, c, d) * .5 + c*.5 + b;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag circle. Circle returns to origin with easing.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: i am using canvas but having problem with my 2 rectangles get on to one another.this is 1 js bin i have created:http://output.jsbin.com/zacacufuxa

Comment: @Learning I don't understand your comment. You should post a new question with more details so we can get a better understanding of what you're wanting to do.

Comment: See i have posted this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208156/update-html-canvas-tag-on-every-ajax-request-with-new-data